# React update dom template after ajax call

Tags: reactjs

I am working with Laravel + React and currently there is markup in the DOM. 
I have a blade container: `<span class="preview-button"` which React renders a button.
When this button gets clicked a modal opens where i would like to change some of its values.

However I am getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: plpModalImg1 is not defined`

How can I update existing modal template after the ajax call?

```html
  <div class='row'>
    <div id="productcontainer" class="col-12">
      <ul class='row'>
      @foreach($arr as $item)
          <li class='col-6'>
          <div class="inner">
            <span class="preview-button" data-title="{{ $item['title'] }}"></span>
          </div>
        </li>
      @endforeach
      </ul>
    </div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-product-container" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-product" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-product">Title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        // NEED TO UPDATE VALUES HERE
        <img id="modal-img1" src="{imgTitle}" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@stop
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class PreviewBtn extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { containerData: "" };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      containerData: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode.getAttribute("data-title"),
      plpModalImg1: document.getElementById("modal-img1"),
    });
  }

  _handleClick(v1){
      var url = '/api/item/' + v1;
      axios
        .post(url)

        // NEED TO UPDATE VALUES HERE
        .then(response => this.setState({ajaxData: response.data},
            ()=> plpModalImg1.setState({
              imgTitle: response.data.itemName
              })
            )
        ) 
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={(e) => this._handleClick(this.state.containerData)} type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-product-container">Preview</button>
    );
  }
}


Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.getElementsByClassName('preview-button'),
  function(el) {
    ReactDOM.render(<PreviewBtn />, el)
  }
)
```

Comment: Just remove the callback passed to the `this.setState` and access the `itemName` via `this.state.ajaxData.itemName`. `plpModalImg1.setState` is wrong. `setState` is undefined for dom node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plpModalImg1` is being defined by you in the state. Which means you have to access it via this.state.plpModalImg1

**Updated answer**

Therefor modify your part similar to the following:

```
this.state.plpModalImg1.setAttribute('src', response.data.fabricName)
```

Comment: I am getting error: `Uncaught TypeError: _this2.state.plpModalImg1.setState is not a function`

Comment: Right... I see, because `plpModalImg1` is actually the element from the page and not a react component with state. Either you provide it as a separate component, or set the title with classic javascript. Similar to the following: `plpModalImg1.setAttribute('src', response.data.fabricName)`

Comment: if you update your answer I will accept it as the solution, thank you.